# Updating ONE textbox from different forms and classes at the same time

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn Csharp and I've done a lot of reading over the days in many different threads, but none seems to fit my problem and my actual knowlege.

I have a Form1 with a textbox called "infobar" to display all kind of information coming from maybe Form2 or methods of other classes.

Doing the update of the infobar from From2 works fine with an event like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
        public delegate void dgNewTexEventHandler(object sender, string NewText);
        public event dgNewTexEventHandler OnNewTextForInfobar_Form1;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cmd_pass_text_to_infobar_Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnNewTextForInfobar_Form1?.Invoke(this, textBox_Form2.Text);
    }
}
```

and subscribing to this event in Form1 with

```
secondForm.OnNewTextForInfobar_Form1 += UpdateInfobar;
```

Now I come to the point where I need to update the infobar also from withing a method of a different class where data processing is done (public class DataProcessing).
I can't seem to get it work with the same event, as this belongs to Form2.
Trying to do it with a second event also did not succeed, as the event in DataProcessing didn't seem to get fired.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void cmd_write_to_infobar_via_class_DataProcessing_with_event_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataProcessing CallMethodInClassDataprocessing = new DataProcessing();
            CallMethodInClassDataprocessing.write_string_to_label_Form1(textBox_Form1.Text);
            CallMethodInClassDataprocessing.OnNewTextForInfobar_DataProcessing += UpdateInfobar;
        }

        private void  UpdateInfobar (object sender, string UpdateText)
        {
            lbl_infobar.Text = UpdateText;
        }
    }

    public class DataProcessing
    {
        public delegate void dgNewTexEventHandler(object sender, string NewText);
        public event dgNewTexEventHandler OnNewTextForInfobar_DataProcessing;

        public void write_string_to_label_Form1(string text)
        {
            // fire event and send text to infobar in Form1 : Does NOT work here! (??)
            OnNewTextForInfobar_DataProcessing?.Invoke(this, text);
        }
    }
```

But to me it doesn't seem to be the right way using multiple events for updating ONE textbox from different Forms or Classes.

Maybe you can advise me a better way, which is clearly structured on not too sophisticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple approach is to prepare a generic handler for this kind of problem

For example we start defining an Interface

```
// If some class wants to implement this interface it needs to
// have a method called WriteMessage that receives a string and returns nothing
public interface IReceiver
{ 
    void WriteMessage(string message);
}
```

Now create a static class whose job is to handle the text passing between the senders and the object that receives and display the message

```
public static class Messenger
{ 
    private static IReceiver recv = null;

    // Initialize the internal variable recv with the instance 
    // passed. We don't care what type is, we are only interested
    // in a class that implements the IReceiver interface
    public static void InitializeReceiver(IReceiver f)
    {
        recv = f;
    }

    // Call whatever class instance has been passed in the Initialize
    // we know for sure that there is a WriteMessage method to call
    public static void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        if(recv != null) recv.WriteMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Now your first form should implement the IReceiver interface

```
public class Form1 : Form, IReceiver
{
    Label l = new Label();
    public Form1()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(l);

        // We pass to the Messenger static class the instance of this form
        // because we implement the IReceiver interface. 
        Messenger.InitializeReceiver(this);
    }

    // This is how we satisfy the Interface requirement. 
    // We add a method called WriteMessage that receives a string 
    // and doesn't return anything
    public void WriteMessage(string message)
    {
        // Do whatever you want the message for this class
        l.Text = message;
    }
}
```

At this point anywhere in your code you could call

```
Messenger.SendMessage("This is a test message");
```

Comment: Works fine!! I Never used interfaces before, but they seem to be nice. Could you please explain a bit more, what you are doing in the Messenger class. It's still a little confusing to me.

Comment: Well, Messenger is a static class so every method is usable without creating instances and you can use these methods in every point of your program (in any form for example). When we call the InitializeReceiver we pass an object that implements the required interface. This could be a form but to the Messenger class this is not known. The only thing that matters is the fact that the object received implements the WriteMessage described in the interface.

Comment: Please take in consideration that this class is not thread safe, you need to always call its SendMessage method from the same UI thread

Comment: Many thanks for your time! That makes it clear to even me.