# How do I pass text from form1 to form2 when "both forms are open"

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two forms "which are both open". I want to send a datagridview cell value from form 1 (already open) to form 2 (already open). (I don't want to pass text on form load, but after some edits on the already open form). I've searched the web for days but I can't find one for already open forms. (Only those containing `form.Show()` property).

Comment: Forms are just classes like any other. How would you pass something to another instance of a class? You will need a reference to the form and then you can call methods on it or set public properties on it.

Comment: There are tons of answers about this problem. You could you to look also at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370983/updating-one-textbox-from-different-forms-and-classes-at-the-same-time/54371472?noredirect=1#comment95579406_54371472

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared singleton class to keep your data

```
/// <summary>
/// A singleton class to keep your application data
/// </summary>
public class MySharedData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when data changes
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler DataChanged;
    private static MySharedData _instance;
    private object _data;

    public static MySharedData Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new MySharedData());

    private MySharedData()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the data you want to share
    /// </summary>
    public object Data
    {
        get => _data;
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnDataChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDataChanged()
    {
        DataChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Use an event to notify che data has updated.

Then in the forms subscribe to the event and add your update logic

```
    public class YourForm : Form
    {
        public YourForm()
        {
            MySharedData.Instance.DataChanged += Instance_DataChanged;
        }

        private void Instance_DataChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: redraw your form
        }
    }
```